# How can I split a column with multiple values into multiple lines while repeating value from 1st column?

Tags: awk, sed, zsh

I'm trying get a list of all my CVEs and my Erratas, the CVE column is comma delimited. I need it to be newline delimited, and the corresponding Errata to be output as well

I can either use sed or awk to accomplish this, but unsure how to get started

Current Output:

```
RHSA-2017:3221  CVE-2016-10167, CVE-2016-10168
RHSA-2015:2369  CVE-2015-3248
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2014-9715, CVE-2015-2666, CVE-2015-2922, CVE-2015-3636
```

Desired Output:

```
RHSA-2017:3221  CVE-2016-10167
RHSA-2017:3221  CVE-2016-10168
RHSA-2015:2369  CVE-2015-3248
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2014-9715
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-2666
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-2922
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-3636
```

Update (Solved):
`awk '{errata=$1; for(i=2; i<NF; i++) {print errata,$i}}' FS=',? +' OFS='  ' /C/Temp/ERRATACVETEST.txt`
 I changed cyrus' a bit, I changed `i<=NF` to `i<NF`, and it yields my desired results, thanks!

Comment: Questions of the type "I need this and have no idea how to do it." are usually considered too broad and often give the impression that the goal of the question is actually to have programming work done free of charge. Please use a HelloWorld of a language of your choice and follow a few basic tutorials. Then, if you have at least the most simple attempt, which is still far from your goal, present it here and describe what is missing.

Comment: I've used awk plenty, I could write some arbitrary code if that would help. I believe I need to store the value from errata column as a variable, and then use awk to split the cve column with ', ' and then do a for loop and print the variable stored from the errata column along with the split values from cve column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
awk '{errata=$1; for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {print errata,$i}}' FS=',? +' OFS='  ' file
```

Output:

```
RHSA-2017:3221  CVE-2016-10167
RHSA-2017:3221  CVE-2016-10168
RHSA-2015:2369  CVE-2015-3248
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2014-9715
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-2666
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-2922
RHSA-2015:1534  CVE-2015-3636
```

---

See [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858) and [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: I use awk version 20021213, I ended up changing the `i<=NF` to `i<NF` and that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^((\S+\s+)[^,]+),\s*/\1\n\2/;P;D' file
```

Substitute a newline and the first field and its spacing for each comma in a line.

Answer (score 0):

A variation of Cyrus post:

```
awk -F',? *' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
RHSA-2017:3221 CVE-2016-10167
RHSA-2017:3221 CVE-2016-10168
RHSA-2015:2369 CVE-2015-3248
RHSA-2015:1534 CVE-2014-9715
RHSA-2015:1534 CVE-2015-2666
RHSA-2015:1534 CVE-2015-2922
RHSA-2015:1534 CVE-2015-3636
```